# ¿Cuál es la forma más rápida de obtener el total de registros de una tabla sqlite en C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

Tengo una tabla con 726.000 registros y utilizaba este método para obtener el total de registros, pero si bien en archivos de menos de 100.000 registros era aceptable, ahora es demasiado lento (76 largos segundos).

```
public static int cantidadRegistros(AControlArchivo awDatosArchivo, string awFiltro)
    {            
        int nwRetorno = 0;
        try
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmdSqlite;
            SQLiteConnection connSqlite;
            string query = "";
            if (awFiltro == null || awFiltro == "")
            {
                query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + awDatosArchivo.awTabla;
            }
            else
            {
                query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + awDatosArchivo.awTabla  + " WHERE " + awFiltro;
            }
            connSqlite = ConnectToSqlite(awDatosArchivo);
            cmdSqlite = new SQLiteCommand();
            cmdSqlite.Connection = connSqlite;
            cmdSqlite.CommandText = query;
            cmdSqlite.Connection.Open();
            nwRetorno = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSqlite.ExecuteScalar());
            cmdSqlite.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            muestroError(ex);
        }
        return nwRetorno;
    }
```

awDatosArchivo tiene dentro la información del: path, el nombre de la base de datos y la tabla.

He encontrado información utilizando linq pero no he sabido adaptarla (mirar al final del articulo.
[Using Query to count related entities without loading them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Si pudieran adaptar este ejemplo de linq, me seria de utilidad para entenderlo.

También he probado cargando la tabla en un dataset y es más rápido.

```
 public static int cantidadRegistros(AControlArchivo awDatosArchivo, string awFiltro)
    {
        int nwRetorno = 0;
        nwRetorno = LeoDataSet(awDatosArchivo, awFiltro).Tables[0].Rows.Count;           
        return nwRetorno;
    }

public static DataSet LeoDataSet(AControlArchivo awDatosArchivo, string awFiltro)
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmdSqlite;
        SQLiteConnection connSqlite;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connSqlite = ConnectToSqlite(awDatosArchivo);
        cmdSqlite = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmdSqlite.Connection = connSqlite;
        StringBuilder awQuery = new StringBuilder();
        awQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM ");
        if (awFiltro == null || awFiltro == "")
        {
            awQuery.Append(awDatosArchivo.awTabla);
        }
        else
        {
            awQuery.Append(awDatosArchivo.awTabla + " " + datosPublicos.awInnerJoin + " WHERE " + awFiltro);
        }
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(awQuery.ToString(), connSqlite);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

Demora 17 segundos pero sigue siendo muy lento.

Comment: Yo no creo que ninguna consulta realizada en LINQ pueda ser más rápida  que un `select count(*)`,que se realiza directamente en el gestor de base de datos. Quizá debas realizar un análisis de tu base de datos para ver como mejorar el rendimiento (cacheo de consultas, uso de indices, etc..)

Comment: Me temo que SQLite es bastante lento con este tipo de consultas, creo que la mejor alternativa que tienes es guardar la información de registros en una tabla, tal vez lo mejor sea usar triggers en inserts y deletes con el fin de alimentar esa tabla.

Comment: David Porqueras, gracias, pero eso no me solucionaría cuando aplico un filtro y deseo ver cuantos registros se ven (cuando hago un datagridview de una tabla, muestro la cantidad total de registros y la cantidad que se visualizan, como datos al margen del datagridview)

Comment: ALERTA: yo utilizo los programas: Valentina Studio y SQlite Expert Personal para visualizar las tablas y probar sentencias sql, ultimamente los estaba utilizando para analizar el tema de la demora en ejecutar una determinada query, y descubri que la primer vez que se ejecuta una query demora pero luego queda en cache pues las siguientes veces la demora es de unos 300ms o menos.

Comment: ¿Es siempre lento, o solo cuando aplicas el filtro?, ¿Has probado de crear índices sobre los campos de búsqueda?, Normalmente los índices aceleran las búsquedas y por tanto también los conteos

Comment: Si, es siempre lento, si utilizo el indice se acelera "SELECT COUNT (col_ID) FROM tabla ORDER BY col_ID y es realmente rápido (en todas las páginas que consulte no se comenta esta mejora, es extraño !!!), está sería una respuesta parcial a mi pregunta. Pero si filtro usando LIKE para buscar los que coinciden sigue siendo lento y no hay indice que lo acelere, pero es bastante rápido si leo toda la base de datos y luego la filtro, esto no tiene sentido, el COUNT debería ser igual o más rapido

Comment: Es muy recomendable que crees índices, pero no debes aplicar funciones sobre el campo al cual le creaste el índice, la otra sería crear un índice compuesto si es que tu consulta lo hace por más de un filtro, pero sin usar funciones sobre los campos por los cuales realizas los filtros.

Comment: @5frags, a que te refieres cuando dices: "aplicar funciones sobre un campo"

Comment: @HugoMariño a que realices un LIKE o un MAX, por ejemplo.

Comment: Quizá si lo que buscas es realizar consultas mas rápidas, debas considerar una reestructura de tus datos, por ejemplo, clasificando con una id (tipo catalogo) cada registro, de esa forma pudieras optimizar tus busquedas... para ello, pudieras proporcionar mas datos, por ejemplo... ¿Que contiene tu string awFiltro que complementa el query? Por supuesto, no debes dejar de lado las sugerencias de creacion de Indices

Answer (score 2):

La consultas que usan indices son más rápidas. En la mayoría de los casos para la clave primaria el gestor crea un indice de forma automática

```
query = @"SELECT COUNT(clave_primaria) FROM " + awDatosArchivo.awTabla;
```

o

```
query = @"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM " + awDatosArchivo.awTabla;
```

Para el caso de los filtros debes considerar usar busquedas de texto completo. ([Full Text Search](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#full_text_index_queries)) Pero esto implica modificar tu base de datos y cambiar la consulta

[In most cases, UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by creating a unique index in the database. (The exceptions are INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and PRIMARY KEYs on WITHOUT ROWID tables.)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Comment: Adicionalmente considera hacer tu método asíncrono  con el uso de async y Task<int>

Answer (score 0):

si ya tienes todos los elementos en un Cursor ..

creo que seria mejor que hagas

```
int cantidad_total = cursor.getCount();
```